# how to make display message in page after click confirm alert in react js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

in my below code using react js i want to make when i click on confirmation alert ok then its show display message success in web page.in my below i when i click on button its confirmation alert is show and when i click on ok then message is not display in web page.

How can we do that is there any help. Its very thankful.

Anyone plz help me out this.

Please check here in my code what i am try to achive

[check](https://codesandbox.io/s/k0nl6871xr?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: anyone plz help me out this?

Comment: Updated your code there, one of the way to show the message, but really depends on your use case. https://codesandbox.io/s/mutable-silence-jwv95?file=/src/index.js

Comment: @Anothercoder thanks for reply in here https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-cspqy?file=/AlertDialog.js i want to make success and unsuccess message show after select agree or disagree

Comment: how can we do that in this code https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-cspqy?file=/AlertDialog.js can u plz help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code sandbox you shared was 'logging' the message rather than displaying on the screen. I have updated the code to update the state according to the option user selected.

```
  handleAgree = () => {
    this.setState({ agreedState: "I agree!" });
    this.handleClose();
  };

  handleDisagree = () => {
    this.setState({ agreedState: "I do not agree!" });
    this.handleClose();
  };
```

And finally we can display the message:

```
{/* Showing message according to the selected option */}
<h1>{this.state.agreedState}</h1>
```

Here is the updated [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-f53ty?file=/AlertDialog.js:1142-1240).

Answer (score 1):

I don't really get what you want to do.

You got the code working to display the question prompt.
If you would like to get rid of that only record, you could simply add a ref to your class Component, like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef(null);
}
```

Then add the function to handle your deletion logic, e.g: make a POST request to delete that specific item.

```
handleRemoveItem = (e) => {

    const res = window.confirm("Delete the item?");
    /**
     * Probably a POST request to delete 
     * the record with the key 'e'.
     * Or handle múltiples refs.
     */ 
    if (res)
      this.myRef.current.remove();
}
```

Add ref to button, and you've already done the rest:

```
<button
  className="btn btn-danger"
  ref={this.myRef}
  onClick={this.handleRemoveItem}
>
```

If you'd like to display an error or success message, add props to your component, so it's reusable across multiple use cases. But, in order to let you visualize this behaviour, this could be useful:

```
{(this.state.error || this.state.success) && (
  <span className="message">
    {this.state.error
      ? this.state.errorMessage
      : this.state.successMessage}
  </span>
)}
```

Add the state to the constructor:

```
this.state = {
  error: false,
  success: false,
  errorMessage: 'Your error message!',
  successMessage: 'Your success messsage'
};
```

Finally, the logic to your handler:

```
handleRemoveItem = (e) => {

    const res = window.confirm("Delete the item?");
    /**
     * Probably a POST request to delete 
     * the record with the key 'e'.
     * Or handle múltiples refs.
     */ 
    if (res) {
      this.myRef.current.remove();
      this.setState({ success: true });
      setTimeout(() => this.setState({ success: false }), 3000);
    } else {
      this.setState({ error: true });
      setTimeout(() => this.setState({ error: false }), 3000);
    }
}
```

[Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-cannon-09cpu?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: ur code is not work its showing error i want to make display success or unsucees messgage after click window alert

Comment: I added what you needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `const res = window.confirm("Delete the item?");` to check click `OK` or `Cancel` from `alert`. After that, you can show your message success as you want when the user clicks OK.

https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-haslett-y63ld?file=/src/index.js

Comment: thank in here https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-cspqy?file=/AlertDialog.js how can we do